# Finding files with and asterisk (*) in the file name

Tags: bash, find

How do I find files with an asterisk in the file name? Another way to ask the question is, how do I get an asterisk to NOT behave as a wildcard?

Typically for a wildcard I would so something like this:

```
$ find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.jpg \)
```

If I don't escape the `*` I get the following

```
$ find ./ -type f \( -iname * \)
find: paths must precede expression: .....
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-iname'?
```

Since the error suggests the `*` needs to be quoted I've tried `find ./ -type f \( -iname "*" \)` or `find ./ -type f \( -iname '*' \)` but this also functions as a wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution appears to be using square brackets `[ ]`.
Of course I solved it 5 min after posting.  I hope this helps someone in the future.

```
$ find . -name '*[*]*' -type f
```

Though one can also use backslash to escape the `*` for `find`

```
$ find . -name '*\**' -type f
```

Singles quotes are used to make sure `*`,`[` and `\` lose the special meaning they also have for *the shell*.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. What find(1) is complaining about is something quite different. Say in the current directory you have files `a`, `b`, `c`. If you call e.g.:

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname * \)
```

what `find` gets is `./ -type f ( -iname a b c )` (shell expands '*' before handing the resulting command line off to it, the parenteses are quoted; exact same result for `***`). If you write:

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \* \)
```

it gets `./ -type f ( -iname * )`,